# Where can I get the Android camera application source code?

Tags: android, camera

I'm referring to the camera application that is already installed on my G1, not the camera API source code.

How do I get the source code?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You will need to *clone* the project from the Android repository using `git`.

The project URL is:

> `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git`

You can clone the project like this:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git
```

The source code will be in the directory *Camera*.

[This link](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) will tell you how to download all the sources.

*<sub>If you need help with using git then checkout git's [documentation section](http://git-scm.com/documentation).</sub>*

Comment: Hi @OctavianDamiean can you please tell me where i can find the sourcecode of stock Contacts app?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal visit [here](https://android.googlesource.com/) and search for _platform/packages/apps_, you will find what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Google has moved hosting to their own servers, so the process has changed. You can no longer browse the kernel source online, but the Android source code can be downloaded from http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.

You'll need a git client, and a lot of time to download the entire source code.

If you don't want the entire current version of Android, here are some alternatives:

- [Online (browsable) snapshot of Android 2.2](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/%20%22Online%20%28browsable%29%20snapshot%20of%20Android%202.2)
- [Google code search (will be discontinued in 2012)](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#search/&q=camera%20package:git://android.git.kernel.org&type=cs)

Searching through these public repos should give you enough code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

These links may be of help to you.

Native code:

- https://code.google.com/p/srv1console/

Customized code:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html
- http://android.bigresource.com/Android-change-existing-apps-code-of-G1-calendar-and-Camera-code-nA0c0sK59.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Answer (score 0):

Recently I looked for Contact stock app in android and I hit this thread. I was able to find the solution.

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera

is the way to clone camera app.

All apps are listed in page

https://android.googlesource.com/

In browser search for packages/apps/ to get the corresponding apps repository name.