# Source Code For stock apps

Tags: android, image-processing, open-source, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to use the source code of stock image editor present in ICS. where can I download it. please help some one. I am new to this field.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: @BrianWillis yeah may be but it looks quite complicated. I just want to download the source of Image Editor (name - Photo studio).

Answer (score 2):

The ICS Image Editor is baked right into the Gallery app. You can find that [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery), where you can [clone the GIT repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository). The Camera source code [is also available](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera). You will find, however, that some aspects of these sources are run natively (in C) and the sources for this I do not believe are publicly available. *(You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105196/where-can-i-get-the-android-camera-application-source-code) useful.)*

[Photo Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kvadgroup.photostudio&hl=en) is a third-party app that is closed-source and not stock.

There is a 3rd party Image Editor source code at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-image-editor/source/browse/). I do warn you: The code may not be as simple as you're hoping for. *(PS: You may want to do some research next time... this was found with [one Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=android+image+editor+source).)*

Comment: Thats not the stock app. but thanks for your effort.

Comment: [Photo Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kvadgroup.photostudio&hl=en) is not the stock app either, nor is it open source...

Comment: thats not the photo studio I am talking about. I am talking about the stalk in-built one thats comes preloaded with ICS.

Comment: The one in ICS is built into the Gallery, assuming we're talking Galaxy Nexus. The source for that is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery).