# How to use camera in android to capture image and video?

Tags: android, android-camera

How to use camera in android so that the user can toggle between the camera mode and recorder mode whilst in the same camera app, as you can see the small slide control in the center of the right side of the image below.

[image: The slide control is circled in red.]

Comment: Please mark the appropriate question as 'best answer' for other users.

Answer (score 9):

The stock camera app is open source. Why not just [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105196/where-can-i-get-the-android-camera-application-source-code) at how it is implemented?

Answer (score 5):

Use Tow Button One For Image and Other for Video in UI....

```
/****  Camera / Video Demo ****************/
public class CameraDemoActivity extends Activity {
    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /*
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        /*
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /*
     * Here we store the file url as it will be 
     * null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /*
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the 
                                                           // image file
                                                           // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method 
     * will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.pause();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
     * */

    /*
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard
        // location.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        // Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add toggle button and set some value in it. let say 0 or 1
and then capture image/record video button.
and when toggle value is 0 call camera method and when toggle value is 1 call video method.

here is code for camera and video recording

[Capture image](http://java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/Camera.htm)

[Record Video](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/android-in-practice/com/manning/aip/media/VideoRecorderActivity.java.htm)

implement both classes methods in one class. and then call onSnapClick for camera and startRecording() for video.

Hope this will help.

Comment: record video link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use default functionality of camera and video like this-

```
Intent intent1    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    String fileName = "KeyICamImage"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".JPG";
                    String mPathImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + fileName;
                    file = new File(mPathImage);
                    mImageCaptureUri= Uri.fromFile( file );

                    try 
                    {

                        intent1.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImageCaptureUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent1, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } 

                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: With `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` we can only capture images but can't record a video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it works or not, but try this

You should have 
`MediaRecorder recorder;
Camera camera;`

Try to switching between video and photo by using 
                `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` 
or `recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` in your `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)`. When you switching you should recreate surfaceView. Stock camera app recreates whole activity.