# Is it possible to use Android's native camera controls/graphics in your own app?

Tags: android, button, camera, native

I don't want my app to open the existing camera app via an intent such as:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents

I basically want to use my own custom Camera object with a SurfaceView (which is simple enough and fully documented) but I want the camera layout to look like the phone's stock graphics for a camera. The take photo button, flash button, etc. though I don't believe I have access the the native android.r.drawables for these specific buttons correct? And I can't simply copy the graphic for a particular button from the sdk folder and put that in my own drawables folder as it has to be dynamic per device to look like that phone's camera app.

Can anyone find official documentation from Android that says this can't be done?  I need to know officially this is or is not doable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the source of the camera app. It contains all of the resources.
See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105311/661079

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the source and it looks like the camera app references it's own resources and not what comes with the SDK. This must be Google's default stock graphics but I'm guessing the Camera app graphics on each phone is Manufacturer/Device specific not from the SDK.