# CWAC Camera auto focus indicator

Tags: android, cwac-camera

I am building a custom camera using cwac-camera library, I have added autofocus while tapping on the screen and I was wondering whether there is a way to show auto-focus rectangular indicator just like in ther apps on the area touched?...

thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Going to try this one out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13753889/4198829 ..